# Unable to install Numpy Getting Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, window

Unable to install **numpy** in Windows 10 system using Command Prompt. I have installed the same earlier, but this time getting following error. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
C:\Users\MyPC>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0498B778>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/52/2c/bf86d762ae65550dc8a7ab8381ba610bb69af6db619b3755f2b73052c6b9/numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x049AA6B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/52/2c/bf86d762ae65550dc8a7ab8381ba610bb69af6db619b3755f2b73052c6b9/numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04A3F028>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/52/2c/bf86d762ae65550dc8a7ab8381ba610bb69af6db619b3755f2b73052c6b9/numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04A3F100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/52/2c/bf86d762ae65550dc8a7ab8381ba610bb69af6db619b3755f2b73052c6b9/numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04A3F1D8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/52/2c/bf86d762ae65550dc8a7ab8381ba610bb69af6db619b3755f2b73052c6b9/numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/52/2c/bf86d762ae65550dc8a7ab8381ba610bb69af6db619b3755f2b73052c6b9/numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04A3F2B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was asked on PIP's GitHub issues: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5448

Adding `--trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org` will likely solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response but, still getting the same error.

C:\Users\MyPC>pip install numpy --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org

Answer (score 0):

When I install numpy from old network which I have used first time, it get installed successfully.

Comment: This is a very poor solution for us, because we do not know what your old network was. Why does it solve the problem?

Comment: True, that why needed a proper solution for this.